# PHP MySql INNER JOIN User ID Error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to grab a message in then show it under my notification tab, but it don't show the message I'm trying to do a INNER JOIN from two table members table and notifications table this is how my table structure is set up.

Members Table

memberID,

username,

ownerIP,

and more

now inside the notification Table this is what i have.

notifications

id

memberID

message

status

this is my php code.

```
                            <li class="dropdown hidden-xs">
                                <a href="#" data-target="#" class="dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <i class="icon-bell"></i> <span class="badge badge-xs badge-danger">3</span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg">
                                <?php 

                                // Load Notfications
                                $loadNotfications = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM notfications INNER JOIN members.memberID ON notfications.memberID = members.memberID WHERE memberID = '".$memberID."'");

                                if($loadNotfications) {
                                    foreach($loadNotfications as $loadNotfication) {
                                        $id = $loadNotfication['id'];
                                        $memberID = $loadNotfication['memberID'];
                                        $message = $loadNotfication['message'];
                                        $status = $loadNotfication['status'];

                                ?>                                  
                                    <li class="notifi-title"><span class="label label-default pull-right">New 3</span>Notification</li>
                                    <li class="list-group nicescroll notification-list">

                                       <!-- list item-->
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
                                            <div class="media">
                                                <div class="pull-left p-r-10">
                                                 <em class="fa fa-cog fa-2x text-custom"></em>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                  <h5 class="media-heading">New settings</h5>
                                                  <p class="m-0">
                                                    <small><?php echo $message; ?></small>
                                                </p>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item text-right">
                                            <small class="font-600">See all notifications</small>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>                                  
                                </ul>
                            </li>
```

I need help with this can anybody help me with this.

Comment: you should try to re-create your database schema on SQL Fiddle. This usually leads to a faster answer. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i resolve my issue this is what i did to fix it

```
                                // Load Notfications
                                $loadNotifications = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE memberID='{$myID}' AND status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25");

                                if($loadNotifications) {
                                    foreach($loadNotifications as $loadNotification) {
                                        $id = $loadNotification['id'];
                                        $memberID = $loadNotification['memberID'];
                                        $message = $loadNotification['message'];
                                        $status = $loadNotification['status'];
                                        $subject = $loadNotification['subject'];
                                ?>                                  

                                       <!-- list item-->
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="list-group-item">
                                            <div class="media">
                                                <div class="pull-left p-r-10">
                                                 <em class="fa fa-bell fa-2x text-custom"></em>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                  <h5 class="media-heading"><?php echo $subject; ?></h5>
                                                  <p class="m-0" style="white-space: normal;">
                                                    <small><?php echo $message; ?></small>
                                                </p>
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </a>

                                <?php
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    echo '<span class="text-center">There are currently no unread notifications.</span>';
                                }
                                ?>

                                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check this line:

```
$loadNotfications = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM notfications INNER JOIN members.memberID ON notfications.memberID = members.memberID WHERE members.memberID = '".$memberID."'");
```

I have put `members.memberId` after the WHERE clause. I think it could work.